# Jenkins job with different maven versions

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I have a maven Jenkins job, that is part of a multijob. Τhis used to run always on windows nodes, but currently we have created some linux nodes, too, that we want to utilize.
The thing is that inside the job,at build step you have to choose:

[image]

This maven version applies when building the job. For example the maven version that applied here,, is linked to the path were maven is installed for windows. So this path, is applicable only for windows nodes, therefore, the job cannot be run by a linux node. Is there a workaround for this?
thanks!

Comment: First define a version in Global Tools Configuration in Jenkins. Than define the tools location for the appropriate node (Node Configuration)...

Comment: @khmarbaise have a look at the screenshot mate, and at the description.the problem occurs an Build stage, at a maven project

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool, What you want to achieve is not possible by Jenkins maven plugin. You can use Jenkins pipeline or script to achieve it. If you are ok with this then I can give you solution for later options

Comment: @Prasad Marne yes sure, i am open to alternatives.could you please share details for both solutions?however i intend to open an issue for this to jenkins team

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool I posted my solution for Jenkins pipeline. I can give you solution for script also if you require.

Comment: @Prasad Marne hey, thanks for the pipeline solution.Could you please send the script solution too, since my project is not a pipeline one?thanks!

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool hey, i have posted the other solution it uses conditional build step plugin. hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using Jenkins pipeline. Just set two maven config in Jenkins > global tool configuration. One for windows maven and other for linux.

```
node {
def mvnHome
stage('Build') {
    // Run the maven build
    if (isUnix()) {
        mvnHome = tool 'Maven-linux'
        sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' clean package "
    } else {
        mvnHome = tool 'Maven-windows'
        bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" clean package /)
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is to use Jenkins [Conditional build step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

- Create freestyle job
- In Build Step select conditional step single or multiple.
- In the Run? you can select execute shell
- In Builder select invoke-top-level-maven-target and select maven-linux in maven version. Then you can configure maven goals and other steps
- In Build Step on again select conditional step single or multiple.
- In the Run? you can select execute windows batch command
- In Builder select invoke-top-level-maven-target and select maven-window in maven version. Then you can configure maven goals and other steps

[image: Jenkins Job setup for above steps.]

Answer (score -1):

Configure your linux slaves:

- Manage jenkins > manage nodes > %node > configure > Node properties
- Then specify mvn and java located on your slave and fill in **Tool ocations**

Comment: this is not exactly what i asked.my point is that even if the node is configured as you said, the project at build step can be configured only once and generically